# Is creating a module with interfaces only a good idea?

Tags: oop, module, architecture

Creating a module (bundle, package, whatever) with only interfaces seems to me a strange idea. Yet, I don't know the other best solution to solve the following architectural requirement.

There often appears a need for a set of utilities. In many projects I can see the creation of "utils" folder, or even a seperate package (module) with frequently used ones.

Now consider the idea that you don't want to depend upon a concrete utils set. Instead you, therefore, use interfaces.

So you may create the whole project, with multiple modules, dependent only on the "Utils-Interfaces" set, which could be a separate module. Then you think you can re-use it in other projects, as these utils are frequently used.

So what do you do? Create a seperate module (package, bundle...) with interfaces with definitions of the methods to be implemented by concrete utility-classes? And re-use this "glue-interfaces-packages" (possibly with other "glues", such as bridges, providers etc.) in your various other projects? Or is there a better way to design the archictecture regarding the utilities that could be easily switched from one to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bit odd to have an interface for utility methods as it should be clear what they do. Also in most language you won't have static dispatch anymore. And you wouldn't solve a problem by having interfaces for utility methods. I think it would make more sense to look for a library doing the same thing or writing your own if such functionality isn't already implemented. Very specific things should be tied to the project, though.

---

Let's look at an example in Java:

```java
public static boolean isDigitOnly(String text) {
    return "\\d+".matches(text);
}
```

Let's assume one would use an interface. That would mean that you have to have an instance of such an implementation, most likely a singleton. So what's the point of that? You would write the method head twice and you don't have any advantage; interfaces are used for loose coupling, however such generic utility methods aren't bound to your application.

So maybe you just want to use a library. And actually there is one for exactly this use case: Apache Commons. Of course you may not want to include such a big library for a single method. However, if you need this many utility methods you may want to use it.

---

Now I've explained how to use and reuse utility methods; however, a part of your question was about using different implementations.

I can't see many cases you wanted this. If, for example, you have a method specific to a certain implementation of sockets, you may instead want

A) the utility method as a part of the API
B) an interface for different socket implementations on which you have one common utility method

If you cannot apply this to your problem, it's probably not a utility method or I didn't consider it. If you could provide me with a more specific problem I'd be happy to give you a more concrete answer.

Comment: Ok, you're right. If the util implementation is in a way specific, then there should be such a requirement from the app itself, i.e. the app depends on it anyway, as the results should be predictable (the same, regardless the implemenattion). Thanks for clearing this out.